# CodeIgniter Active Record - Prevent duplicates, sorted by date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

The tried code:

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('documents_table');
    $this->db->order_by("last_modified_date", "desc");
    $this->db->group_by('document_id');

    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Table structure:

id , document_id , content , last_modified_date

Problem:

The design of the system means that when documents are updated, a actual new record is created with  the same document_id and the updated content.

Now I need the documents displayed in a list, however if they are multiple documents with the same document_id (basically older versions of the file), only the latest version should be displayed. The current code outputs the first versions only, so this needs to be switched.

Is group_by the right method for this? Anyone with some experience can work out why its not working as intended, or am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('documents_table');
$this->db->order_by("last_modified_date", "desc");    
$this->db->where('id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM documents_table GROUP BY document_id)');
```

Give that one a try (untested).

Comment: Perfect! Works as needed! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->db->select('MAX(id) , document_id , content , last_modified_date');
 $this->db->from('documents_table');
 $this->db->order_by("last_modified_date", "desc");
 $this->db->group_by('document_id');

 $query = $this->db->get();
```

Untested

Comment: Nope. Still getting the old records instead of the latest one.